# how to remove externally loaded swf with a close button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild

i've a 3d carousel script..when one of the instance is clicked, it will load an external swf(with close_btn in it) as its content..it worked all fine...the problem is how do i remove the externally loaded swf with the close_btn...this is my code in my main timeline :

```
var centerX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2;
var centerY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
var radiusX:Number = 180;
var radiusY:Number = 50;
var speed:Number = 0.1;
var minSpeed:Number = -0.15;
var maxSpeed:Number = 0.15;
var rangeSpeed:Number = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
var minY:Number = centerY - radiusY;
var maxY:Number = centerY + radiusY;
var rangeY:Number = maxY - minY;
var minScale:Number = 0.5;
var maxScale:Number = 1.2;
var rangeScale:Number = maxScale - minScale;
var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
var itemArray:Array =[perkhidmatan, misi, tentang, members];
var fileNames : Array = ["perkhidmatan.swf", "misi.swf", "tentang.swf","members.swf",];


var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(canvas);

for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
canvas.addChild(itemArray[i]);
itemArray[i].buttonMode = true;
itemArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToURL);
itemArray[i].itemAngle = Math.PI * 2 / itemArray.length * i;
itemArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
}

function goToURL(e:MouseEvent):void {
for (var i:int = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
if (e.currentTarget == itemArray[i]) {
    my_loader.load(new URLRequest(fileNames[i]));
    trace(fileNames[i]);
    trace(my_loader);
    addChild(my_loader);
    itemArray[i].mouseEnabled = false;
    itemArray[i].alpha = 0.5;
} else {
    itemArray[i].mouseEnabled = true;
    itemArray[i].alpha = 1;
}
}
}

function animate(e:Event):void
{
speed = mouseX / stage.stageWidth * rangeSpeed + minSpeed;
e.currentTarget.x = Math.cos(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusX + centerX;
e.currentTarget.y = Math.sin(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusY + centerY;
e.currentTarget.itemAngle += speed;
itemArray.sortOn("y");




for(var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
canvas.setChildIndex(itemArray[i], i);
var pct:Number = (itemArray[i].y - minY) / rangeY;
var scale:Number = pct * rangeScale + minScale;
itemArray[i].scaleX = itemArray[i].scaleY = scale;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Unload or remove from the stage?

Comment: whats the different between them?..i just want the loaded swf remove from the stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it sounds like you want to add a click listener to a display object inside the loaded swf that when clicked will remove the loaded swf from the stage.

So here's what I would do:

```
function goToURL(e:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
        if (e.currentTarget == itemArray[i]) {
            my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE. onLoaderComplete );
            my_loader.load(new URLRequest(fileNames[i]));
            trace(fileNames[i]);
            trace(my_loader);
            //addChild(my_loader); //do not add the loader to this display object
            itemArray[i].mouseEnabled = false;
            itemArray[i].alpha = 0.5;
        } else {
            itemArray[i].mouseEnabled = true;
            itemArray[i].alpha = 1;
        }
    }
}

function onLoaderComplete( e:Event ):void {
    //set a variable called _loadedSwf as type MovieClip at the top
    _loadedSwf = e.target.content;
    _loadedSwf.close_btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, removeLoadedSwf );
    addChild( _loadedSwf );
}

function removeLoadedSwf( e:MouseEvent ):void {
    removeChild( _loadedSwf );
}
```

I haven't tested this but I believe that is what you are looking for? Either way hope this helps you out!

Comment: tq @P1on..but i get this error Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 76 1119: Access of possibly undefined property close_btn through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: Yes I suspected you might. So that is an issue with where your close button exists in the display object hierarchy. That means if your close_btn is on the stage in your loaded swf then you just need to make sure it has an instance name ( select the close button and give it the name close_btn and the code I pasted should work ). Otherwise if your close button is elsewhere like in a movieclip on the stage then you will need to delve deeper in the hierarchy, so _loaderSwf.someMovieclip.close_btn.addEventListener so on and so forth. Make sure you close_btn has an instance name though! :)

Comment: Oh I see the error you might have, _loadedSwf typed to display object. If you set _loadedSwf to MovieClip, that should do it (display object won't let you go through the hierarchy but DisplayObjectContainer will. )

Comment: yes.i've done that earlier..it returned the error when i did the test movie on my main file..its not when i clicked on the instance where it load the movie..  ..do i have to set a variable called "close_btn" on top of the script on my main file?

Comment: owh i forgot to tell u..instead of using:
my_loader.load(new URLRequest(fileNames[i]));

i've changed to this:
my_loader.load(new URLRequest(e.currentTarget.name + ".swf"));

Comment: Well it's difficult to discern without seeing how your fla is setup containing the close_btn asset. But you say you have the _loadedSwf set to MovieClip and you are doing _loadedSwf.close_btn and that is returning a null reference error? It would sound like either your close_btn doesn't have an instance name, it's parent doesn't have an instance name, or possibly even both. To set an instance name you need to make sure you select the asset on the stage, then in the properties tab give it a name.

Comment: so how do i put my fla here for u to see?

Comment: You can upload it somewhere and paste a link to it.

Comment: Yes and I found the issue. First you don't have the contentLoaderInfo event in there under your goToUrl function.

Then the other issue is that your close_btn asset only exists on frame 80 in your asset timeline. So when your swf is loaded it is on frame 0 and we are trying to add an event to close_btn which doesn't exist on that frame. I edited your .fla with the frame change. https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9n79an69sp29ys/stackoverflow_p1on_updated.zip

Comment: u're such a help p1on...now i understand the rules of controlling an asset in loaded swf...also the function of contentLoaderInfo..should i mark the above answer as correct answer?can i add u on fb or skype or something?

Comment: Yes please mark it correct as it may be beneficial to someone else having the same problem :) Feel free to email me, ( see my profile for more information, email is on my website ). Good luck!